# g++-4.6.real: error: unrecognized option '-R'

Tags: c, boost, build, autotools, libtool

I am trying to compile [phpcompiler](http://phpcompiler.org) from source using this configure command.

```
./configure  --prefix=/opt/phc-0.3.0.1/    --with-php=/opt/php-5.3.17/
```

The configure error was,

```
checking for exit in -lboost_regex-mt... no
checking for exit in -lboost_regex-mt... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... no
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... (cached) no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_regex
```

Thats completely wrong as I have both boost and boost_regex packages installed. Both libs and header files.  Then I dug this in the `config.log` file

```
configure:17053: g++ -o conftest -g -O2    -L/lib/php5 -L/usr/lib/php5 conftest.cpp /usr/lib/libCrun.so.1 -lphp5 -L/opt/php-5.3.17//lib -R/opt/php-5.3.17//lib -ldl  >&5
g++-4.6.real: error: /usr/lib/libCrun.so.1: No such file or directory
g++-4.6.real: error: unrecognized option '-R'
```

So, for this `unrecognized option '-R'` error, many `-lboost_regex` checks were failed!

How can I fix this? is there any file that I can edit to fix it? And why `-R` is used? I think it would be `-L` flag.

Comment: One way to tackle this kind of question on Linux: Run `strace -o st.log -s 10240 -f -e open,read ./configure` to see which files are opened and read by configure and its child processes. You can search `st.log` to see where `-R` was read from, and with a bit of luck edit the file in question.

Comment: GCC has gotten a lot pickier about options it doesn't recognize (it used to silently ignore them).  The `-R` option is probably intended for the linker, so when you find it try adding a `-Wl,` in front of it (with no space).  Also, note that the `-R` linker option probably really should be `-rpath` (`-R` behaves differently if the argument is a file or directory; if it's a directory it's treated as a `-rpath` option).

Comment: @MvG I dont want to track it that way. It can be fixed by modified automake files!

Comment: @MichaelBurr its intended for linker. I am quite sure about it. how do I add `-Wl`? like `-WlR` or `-Wl-R` ?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: `-Wl,-R/opt/php-5.3.17//lib`  Note the comma and there can't be any spaces (if you need spaces, use additional `-Wl,` options).

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, so you already have found a place in the automake files where this came from? You might have said as much in your question. I assumed that libtool files, package configuration files and so on might be possible sources of this flag as well.

Comment: @MvG Well I tagged with [tag:autotools]. I think that covers it.  I still cant find it. I fixed the error by modifying `./configure` file  as suggested by MichaelBurr. But its goes away when I run `./autogen.sh`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr could you answer with a bit description? I want to accept that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629042/g-4-6-real-error-unrecognized-option-r#comment17037881_12629042) indicates that this `-R` option comes from `configure`, the following line in [`m4/php-embed.m4`](http://code.google.com/p/phc/source/browse/trunk/m4/php-embed.m4?spec=svn3418&r=3358#26) appears to be the most likely source:

```
LIBS="-lphp5 -L${PHP_INSTALL_PATH}/lib -R${PHP_INSTALL_PATH}/lib $LIBS"
```

If you look at `configure`, all other occurrences of `-R` will write that as `${wl}-R`, where `${wl}` will most likely expand to `-Wl,`. So one way to fix this would be adding the `${wl}` before `-R` in the above line and running `autogen.sh` to recreate `configure`.

You may whish to file [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/phc/issues/list) for this, after checking existing ones.

Comment: I filed a issue on their github. they moved to github now

Comment: Thanks for finding the root cause!

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, perhaps you can provide a link here. I can't even find that project on github, and no indication about the move on the project homepage. Obviously I didn't find your issue ticket either.

Comment: I am not sure if its official. But the [repo](https://github.com/pbiggar/phc) is from the maintainer himself. And I see very recent commits there too. See the [issue](https://github.com/pbiggar/phc/issues/8).

Answer (score 0):

You can see a similar error (and resolution) in Git 2.23 (Q2 2019) where `-R` has been removed.
The way of specifying the path to find dynamic libraries at runtime
has been simplified.
The old default to pass `-R/path/to/dir` has been replaced with the new default to pass `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/dir`, which is the more recent GCC uses.

See [commit 0f50c8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f50c8e32c872097f86c424a17e2e4f856bd2f6e) (17 May 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 51d6c0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51d6c0f0159a7f8ec02bc5a095172cee857b4e3a), 13 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `Makefile`: remove the `NO_R_TO_GCC_LINKER` flag
>
> Change our default `CC_LD_DYNPATH` invocation to something GCC likes
>   these days.
>   Since the GCC 4.6 release unknown flags haven't been passed through to [ld(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld). Thus our previous default of `CC_LD_DYNPATH=-R` would cause an error on modern GCC unless `NO_R_TO_GCC_LINKER` was set.
>
> Our use of "`-R`" dates back to [455a7f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/455a7f3275d264f6e66045b92c83747ec461dda5) ("More portability.",
>   2005-09-30, Git v0.99.8a).
>   Soon after that in [bbfc63d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbfc63dd78037a3f94c3f342384caee1037d09ab) ("`gcc` does not necessarily pass runtime libpath with `-R`", 2006-12-27, Git v1.5.0-rc1) the `NO_R_TO_GCC` flag was added, allowing optional use of "`-Wl,-rpath=`".
>
> Then in [f5b904d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5b904db6b02e0ded76732eabe106069a87859fd) ("Makefile: Allow CC_LD_DYNPATH to be overriden",
>   2008-08-16, Git v1.6.1-rc1) the ability to override this flag to something else
>   entirely was added, as some linkers use neither "`-Wl,-rpath,`" nor "`-R`".
>
> From what I can tell we should, with the benefit of hindsight, have
>   made this change back in 2006.
>   GCC & `ld` supported this type of invocation back then, or since at least [binutils-gdb.git](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git)'s.
>   a1ad915dc4 ("[...]Add support for `-rpath`[...]", 1994-07-20).
>
> Further reading and prior art can be found at:
>
> - [tsuna/boost.m4 issue 15](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/issues/15)
> - [Gnome issue 641416](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641416)
> - [Building cURL passing the `-R` option to linker](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-11/0005.html)
>
> Making a plain "`-R`" an error seems from reading those reports to have been
>   introduced in [GCC 4.6 released on March 25, 2011](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html), but I couldn't
>   confirm this with absolute certainty, its release notes are ambiguous
>   on the subject, and I couldn't be bothered to try to build & bisect it
>   against GCC 4.5.