# Compiling error: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’

Tags: python, linux, compilation

I am trying to run an installation using the line:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

To install a dataset reader from: [github](https://github.com/jchelly/read_eagle)

But when I do I get the error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’
```

Which is a compiling issue related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629042/g-4-6-real-error-unrecognized-option-r)

But when I track the error source:

```
C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC
```

I find no file to alter in

> /home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat

to fix the -R issues.

"read_eagle" was downloaded on 03/07/2018 with identity number: 4a73486d8248d16bfd5dc28283e6160156dc28c5 on the history from: github.com/jchelly/read_eagle

I have the following program versions:

Conda: 4.4.11

Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

Full error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_read_eagle' extension
C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

compile options: '-I/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/include -I/home/username/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c'
gcc: ./src/_read_eagle.c
gcc: ./src/read_eagle.c
./src/read_eagle.c: In function ‘get_dataset_list’:
./src/read_eagle.c:194:13: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for(i=0; i<nobj; i+=1)
             ^
./src/read_eagle.c: In function ‘count_particles_with_index’:
./src/read_eagle.c:948:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
          for(i=0;i<n;i+=1)
                   ^
./src/read_eagle.c:960:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
          for(i=0;i<n;i+=1)
                   ^
./src/read_eagle.c: In function ‘read_extra_dataset’:
./src/read_eagle.c:1250:26: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for(ipart=0;ipart<dims[0];ipart+=1)
                          ^
gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/username/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/username/anaconda3/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_read_eagle.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/read_eagle.o -L/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib -L/home/username/anaconda3/lib -R/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib -lhdf5 -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/_read_eagle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’
error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/username/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/username/anaconda3/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_read_eagle.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/read_eagle.o -L/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib -L/home/username/anaconda3/lib -R/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib -lhdf5 -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/_read_eagle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Which Python, Conda, gcc and read_eagle (commit hash) versions? I can build the 4a73486 version fine with Python 3.7 and no Conda (both gcc 8.1 and clang 9.1); it may be a Conda issue.

Comment: I suspect is is a Conda issue. Conda: 4.4.11, Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit), gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, read_eagle has no version numbers I am aware of.

Comment: "read_eagle has no version numbers". That's why I asked for the commit has for read_eagle; or a date when you downloaded it (and from where). Also, please [edit] the relevant into your comments, to make it clearer: comments can be easier to ignore (and should be, in the end).

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6340

Comment: read_eagle was downloaded today with identity number: 4a73486d8248d16bfd5dc28283e6160156dc28c5 on the history from: https://github.com/jchelly/read_eagle .

Comment: If you have no file "/home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat", could you try the following on the Python prompt: `>>> import sysconfig; sysconfig.get_config_var("CC")` and let us know what that gives?

Comment: I have the file: "/home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat"  but nothing in it other than a readme and an ld file of some kind. 

However when I run your command I get: "gcc -pthread -B /home/username/anaconda3/compiler_compat"

Comment: Try running `CC='gcc -pthread' python setup.py build`. If that works, try `CC='gcc -pthread' python setup.py install --user`.

Comment: I tried both of these and got the same "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’ " error -sorry for the late reply.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It seems this is pretty hard (and badly) baked into Conda's gcc. I'm out of ideas, but you may want to take it up as an issue on the Conda website, mailing list or the GitHub page (if the previously linked issue doesn't help).